# How to install OpenCV on Mac using Visual Studio

Tags: c++, macos, visual-studio, opencv

I want to install OpenCV on my Mac but instead of using XCode, I was wondering if it is posible to install an use it with Visual Studio using C++?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/08/17/install-opencv-4-on-macos/ . Maybe this could be a helpful source.

Comment: Not sure Visual Studio for Mac comes with a C++ compiler??

Comment: I don't think VS for Mac supports any C++ development at all. It seems to be a pure .net environment.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "using Xcode". Do you mean for compiling OpenCV itself, or for developing programs using OpenCV? If you're trying to compile OpenCV, then the command line tools installed during installation of Xcode are required. Once you have compiled and installed the OpenCV library, you can use any IDE you want to develop programs (although, as others have said, VS for Mac doesn't support C++ development).

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.

Just go to the extensions tab and search for a C++ Microsoft extension and install it.

It worked for me!

Comment: There is no extension with C++ in Visual Studio for Mac